# How to 'read.csv' many files in a folder using R?

Tags: r

How can I read many CSV files and make each of them into data tables?

I have files of 'A1.csv' 'A2.csv' 'A3.csv'......   in Folder 'A'

So I tried this.

```
link <- c("C:/A")
filename<-list.files(link)
listA <- c()

for(x in filename) {
 temp <- read.csv(paste0(link , x), header=FALSE)
 listA <- list(unlist(listA, recursive=FALSE), temp)
 }
```

And it doesn't work well. How can I do this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a regex to match the filenames

```
reg_expression <- "A[0-9]+"
files <- grep(reg_expression, list.files(directory), value = TRUE)
```

and then run the same loop but use `assign` to dynamically name the dataframes if you want

```
for(file in files){
    assign(paste0(file, "_df"),read.csv(file))
}
```

But in general introducing unknown variables into the scope is bad practice so it might be best to do a loop like

```
dfs <- list()
for(index in 1:length(files)){
    file <- files[index]
    dfs[index] <- read.csv(file)
}
```

Comment: Your last code block is the `for`-loop variant of a "good practice": reading multiple similar files into a list of frames. I suggest you can reduce this significantly with `lapply` (or `sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)`, both for readability and code-golf.

Answer (score 2):

Unless each file is a completely different structure (i.e., different columns ... the number of rows does not matter), you can consider a more efficient approach of reading the files in using `lapply` and storing them in a list. One of the benefits is that whatever you do to one frame can be immediately done to all of them very easily using `lapply`.

```r
files <- list.files(link, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "csv$")
list_of_frames <- lapply(files, read.csv)
# optional
names(list_of_frames) <- files # or basename(files), if filenames are unique
```

Something like `sapply(list_of_frames, nrow)` will tell you how many rows are in each frame. If you have something more complex,

```r
new_list_of_frames <- lapply(list_of_frames, function(x) {
  # do something with 'x', a single frame
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The most immediate problem is that when pasting your file path together, you need a path separator. When composing file paths, it's best to use the function `file.path` as it will attempt to determine what the path separator is for operating system the code is running on. So you want to use:

`read.csv(files.path(link , x), header=FALSE)`

Better yet, just have the full path returned when listing out the files (and can filter for .csv):

`filename <- list.files(link, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "csv$")`

Combining with the idea to use `assign` to dynamically create the variables:

```
link <- c("C:/A")
files <-list.files(link, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "csv$")

for(file in files){
  assign(paste0(basename(file), "_df"), read.csv(file))
}
```